# Manually Creating a Paginator (Laravel 5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I seem to be unable to manually create an instance of the paginator.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class Blah {
    public function index(Paginator $paginator)
    {
        // Build array
        $var = $paginator->make($array, $count, 200);
        return $var;
    }
}
```

From here I'm just getting `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $items ]] in class Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator`

Comment: Search API, isn't paginator abstract or something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no more make() method in laravel 5. You need to create an instance of either an `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` or `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` . Take a look at documentation page, ***Creating A Paginator Manually*** part

http://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination

I guess it'll look something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class Blah {
    public function index()
    {
        // Build array
        $array = [];
        return new Paginator($array, $perPage);;
    }
}
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27546775/975850) answer.

Answer (score 2):

To manualy paginate items in Laravel you should instantiate the `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` class like this:

```
// array of items
$items = [ 'a' => 'ana', 'b' => 'bla', 'c' => 'cili' ]; 

// items per page
$perPage = 2; 

// let paginator to regonize page number automaticly
// $currentPage = null; 

// create paginator instance
$paginate = new Paginator($items, $perPage);
```

Comment: What if I want to show the second page?

Comment: Just send another request with query param "?page=2"