# how to create pagination in laravel when data is in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, pagination

I am trying to create pagination in laravel but any method i write it say call to member function on array

controller function

```
 public function city(city $job_city)
    {

        $data = privatejobcity::where('city_id', $job_city->id)->orderBy('city_id', 'DESC')->get();

        $private_job = [];
        foreach ($data as $values) {

            $private_job[] = private_jobadb::with('cities')->where('id', $values->private_jobabd_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
        }


        return view('frontend.jobTestCatagory.jobsByCities', compact('data', 'private_job'));
}
```

View

```
 <h6>Showing<span>{{$private_job->firstItem()}}
                        - {{$private_job->count()}}</span>of {{$private_job->total()}}
                        jobs</h6>
                        {{ $private_job->links() }}
```

i know i converted data in an array but how can I convert it into an object so I can use these methods `links() count() total()`

Comment: try wrapping the array in collection

Comment: how? can u give me demo

Comment: Collection does not seem to work.  But You can Manually Create A Paginator in laravel. Go to this docs page https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator

Comment: The answer you are looking for is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240758/manually-creating-a-paginator-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function city(city $job_city)
{

    $data = privatejobcity::where('city_id', $job_city->id)->orderBy('city_id', 'DESC')->get();

    $private_job = [];
    foreach ($data as $values) {

        $private_job[] = private_jobadb::with('cities')->where('id', $values->private_jobabd_id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
    }

    $private_job = collect($private_job);


    return view('frontend.jobTestCatagory.jobsByCities', compact('data', 'private_job'));
}
```

Comment: now it says `links() count() total()` does not exist

Comment: can you edit your question with your schema? what is private_job output you expect? before going further, what is the difference between privatejobcity and privat_jobadb, if these two models are related, we can create relation in each model and of course make coding simpler