# Laravel 5 how to use pagination with files list?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I have one problem with my script. I did foreach with files list but I need pagination, for example 15 files per site. What should I do now? Thanks for help :)

Controller:

```
$files = Storage::allFiles('/upload_file');

return view('cms.viewSystem.gallery.manageFiles')->with('files', $files);
```

Blade view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped datatable" id="table-2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nazwa pliku</th>
            <th>Akcje</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($files as $file)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $file }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ url('cms/media/deleteFile/'.$file) }}" class="btn btn-red btn-sm btn-icon icon-left"><i class="entypo-cancel"></i>Usuń</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried use paginate() but this option not working :(

Comment: You can create your own `Paginator` instance and pass it the required parameters for pagination (it's mentioned in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator), but  there are no examples there. For an example you can have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27546775/351330).

Comment: You can use Paginator - look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213453/laravel-5-manual-pagination/27546775#27546775

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
$page = (int) $request->input('page') ?: 1;

$files = collect(Storage::allFiles('/upload_file'));
$onPage = 15;

$slice = $files->slice(($page-1)* $onPage, $onPage);

$paginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($slice, $files->count(), $onPage);
return view('cms.viewSystem.gallery.manageFiles')->with('files', $paginator);
```

And for displaying in view you can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view

Comment: Ok thanks, but I have one problem with that. When I use Pagination function as you said I see navigation page but my foreach show all files on one page, have you idea for that?

Comment: @StanisławSzewczyk I've updated the code - you need to create slice on your own here.

Answer (score 1):

The `Storage::allFiles()` function simply returns an array, so you can use the build in laravel pagination classes. See the docs on pagination https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination

```
$paginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($items, $total, $perPage);

return view('my.view', ['files' => $paginator]);
```

In your view you then loop over the results as normal, but also have access to the `render()` function to display pagination links.

```
@foreach($files as $file)
    {{ $file }}
@endforeach

{!! $files->render() !!}
```