# laravel pagination without a model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

I found this reply this for a similar question:
[Laravel 5 - Manual pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213453/laravel-5-manual-pagination/27546775#27546775)

what is not clear now to me is how to make the front page workin with the classic `{{$items->links()}}` on blade template.

my controller's code is:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($risultati, count($risultati),'10');
```

The problem is that the object that i generate is something like:

```
    LengthAwarePaginator {#311 ▼
  #total: 11
  #lastPage: 2
  #items: Collection {#312 ▶}
  #perPage: "10"
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "/"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

so the problem si in the "path", how can I make it works again?
thanks a lot

Comment: It looks like you can set the path on your `$paginator` variable, just use `$paginator->setPath("example")` and see if that helps. Here's the documentation for that component:  https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method_setPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to pass arguments to LengthAwarePaginator method:

> $paginate = 20;
>
> $page = Input::get('page', 1);
>
> $offSet = ($page * $paginate) - $paginate;
>
> $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($items, $offSet, $paginate, true);
>
> $result = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator ( $itemsForCurrentPage,
> count($items), $paginate,
> LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage(),array('path' =>
> LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath()));

Comment: how can make this part works with request instead of input? $page = Input::get('page', 1);

Comment: @JahStation You can use request to get the page number. 
**$page = $request->page**